# Ms Excel 2016 - customizing spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Just wanted to know how to have a colour pop up on the spread sheet when no information has been entered for the required field if that makes sense?

also how can i prompt the spread sheet fields to only have a date entered nothing else to ensure accuracy for reporting to avoid free writing in fields if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

For the color thing, you'll use **Conditional Formatting**.

You select the cells you want to have colored if blank. Go to **Conditional Formatting**, Select **New Rule**, Over there select **Format Only Cells That Contain** and set it in the bottom to **Blanks**. Select the format you want to apply and press okay.

Here's a short animation of how to do it:
[image]

---

For the second thing, you'll need to use **Data Validation**.

Select the cells you want to have this restriction. Go to the **Data** tab, and over there to **Data Validation**. In the **Allow** dropdown select **Date** and enter a start and end date (can be 01/01/1900 until 12/12/2099...) and click Ok. This is it!

Here, again, is a small animation of how it's done:
[image]